# How to get this from javascript object

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have this code in chrome developer tools,

```
oListItem.get_item('Fruits'): Array[1]
0: SP.FieldLookupValue
$1E_1: 2
$2d_1: "Big Round Apples;#Small Round Apples;"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

How can I get text `Big Round Apples;#Small Round Apples;`

at the moment using this code,

```
oListItem.get_item('Fruits').val();
```

I am getting   `Object object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple `SP.LookupField` value is represented as array of [SP.FieldLookupValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff407817%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

```
//Get Multiple Lookup Field value
var fruitValues = item.get_item('Fruits'); 
for(var i = 0; i < fruitValues.length; i++) {
   var fruitValue = fruitValues[i];
   var fruitLabel = fruitValue.get_lookupValue();
   var fruitId = fruitValue.get_lookupId();
}
```